# Windows Connection Status using CMD

Tags: windows, networking, status

In windows for example local area Connection Status, there are some activity statistics that show network activity as bytes send and bytes received. I need to get this numbers periodically in cmd. Is there any way to get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is exactly what you are asking for, but `netstat` command includes a `-e` switch to retrieve ethernet statistics.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=2,3" %%a in ('netstat -e ^| find "Bytes"') do (
        echo Sent: %%a Received : %%b
    )
```

For protocol specific information the `-s` and `-p` switches will give aditional information (run `netstat /?` to get more information)